# How can I display a specific class for an individual with SPARQL?

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl

I used Protege to create a small ontology.

I start with a class A, a class B, and a class C. Class C contains the subclasses x, y and z. The individuals populating this ontology fall under two classes: the first class is either A or B, the second one is one of the subclasses of C.

I want to retrieve all individuals which have a property H, and which are also either part of class x or y, but not z. I have been able to do that with the following query:

```
SELECT ?individual
    WHERE {?individual ont:hasH ?individual.
        FILTER(NOT EXISTS { ?individual rdf:type ont:z } )}
```

(ont is the prefix for my ontology)

This query does what I want. But for these individuals, I would also like to know whether they are part of class x or y. I've tried changing my query to the following, to no avail:

```
SELECT ?individual ?class
    WHERE {?individual ont:hasH ?individual.
        FILTER(NOT EXISTS { ?individual rdf:type ont:z } ) ?class rdf:type ont:C}
```

Since x and y belong to class C, what I need to know what the class C of the selected individuals is. How could I do that?

(Please bear in mind that I'm completely new to SPARQL.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say a couple of things that make the issue a bit confusing:

> I start with a class A, a class B, and a class C. Class C contains the
>   subclasses x, y and z.
>
> …
>
> Since x and y belong to class C,

We don't usually say that a class *contains* subclasses;  we just say that a class *has* subclasses, or that one class is a subclass of another.  When A is a subclass of B, then whenever some i is an A (i.e., we have the triple [i rdf:type A]), then i is also a B (i.e., we have the triple [i rdf:type B]).

At any rate, you can do the following to find out, for each individual that has an ont:hasH property and is not an instance of ont:z, whether it's an ont:x or an ont:y:

```sql
SELECT ?individual ?class WHERE {
  #-- The first part, which you already provided, ensures that 
  #-- ?individual has a value for ont:hasH, and does not have 
  #-- type ont:z .
  ?individual ont:hasH ?individual.
  FILTER( NOT EXISTS { ?individual rdf:type ont:z } )

  #-- Since each of these individuals also has type ont:x or
  #-- ont:y, you can bind a variable to ont:x and ont:y and 
  #-- match against it, too.  For each result, ?xy will be 
  #-- bound to either ont:X or ont:y, depending on what type 
  #-- ?individual has.
  values ?xy { ont:x ont:y }
  ?individual rdf:type ?xy
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation!
That 'values' keyword is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You can read more about it in the [SPARQL 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/).  As a general practice, it's a good idea to at least skim through the specification or manual of a tool that you're using.  You don't need to memorize everything about it, but planting the seed so that when an issue comes up your mind says "I think I saw *something* that *might* be useful here," is very helpful.